# convert the db itemsinto one language to another language

Tags: android

Hi in my application first time i am inserting some data into sqlite db through assets,first time means installation time.next time onwards i am getting the values from db.Now my question is if the user chnage the language of the device automatically  how that db values(Grocery names) are also changed? Please give me some suggestions.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can preset all the language supported value into the db. and when using the data, the app can filter the value by the locale the used selected.